# Last line and char of text file

Tags: php, fopen

I want to display the last chars from a textfile. The textfile is from a temperature 1-wire system. The file is sometimes big. I display the last line with this:

```
<?php 
$file = file("file.txt");
for ($i = count($file)-1; $i < count($file); $i++) {
echo $file[$i] . "\n";
}
?>
```

It works great!

But how do I read the last 5 chars of that line? I want to and echo them in to a div on an html-page?

regards
Anders

Answer (score 1):

Try below in for loop

```
echo substr($file[$i], -5) . "\n";
```

More Info: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) passing a negative value for the `start` argument.

```
echo "last 5 chars: " . substr($file[$i], -5);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!
I now read, round and display the temperature with this PHP:

```
<?php 
$file = file("file.txt");
for ($i = count($file)-1; $i < count($file); $i++) {
echo round(substr($file[$i], -5) . "\n", 1);
}
```

However problem when there is more or less characters.
Is there a way to read the last characters after the semicolon on the last line?
Three examples:

07.07.2012; 06:19:23;25.63 - display 25.6

09.12.2012; 06:19:23;-5.63 - display -5.6

12.09.2012; 22:58:49;-17.86 - display -17.9

regards
Anders